# How to add the floating buttons in VrPanoramaView for the navigation as shown in the image?

Tags: android, google-vr

I have used the VrpanoramaView and gvrView. I face problem to make the navigation links in panorama image. How can I make the navigation buttons in panorama images using Google VR sdk in android?

[image]

Comment: Haw any solutions?

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [google reference](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/common/VrWidgetView.html#public-methods) will find out there is no default setting
to handle touch events or add navigation buttons.

Even though you write your custom touch events, you cannot connect it to vrView; because this class have no method to set your view angles like setHeadRotation.
I think this mehtod will be added in next versions.